# Large scale static file ( csv txt etc ) archiving solution

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, bigdata

I am new to large scala data analytics and archiving so I though I ask this question to see if I am looking at things the right way.

Current requirement:

- I have large number of static files in the filesystem. Csv, Eml, Txt, Json
- I need to warehouse this data for archiving / legal reasons
- I need to provide a unified search facility **MAIN functionality**

Future requirement:

- I need to enrich the data file with additional metadata
- I need to do analytics on the data
- I might need to ingest data from other sources from API etc.

I would like to come up with a relatively simple solution with the possibility that I can expand it later with additional parts without having to rewrite bits. Ideally I would like to keep each part as a simple service.

As currently search is the KEY and I am experienced with Elasticsearch I though I would use ES for distributed search.

I have the following questions:

- Should I copy the file from static storage to Hadoop?
- is there any virtue keeping the data in HBASE instead of individual files ?
- is there a way that once a file is added to Hadoop I can trigger an event to index the file into Elasticsearch ?
- is there perhaps a simpler way to monitor hundreds of folders for new files and push them to Elasticsearch?

I am sure I am overcomplicating this as I am new to this field. Hence I would appreciate some ideas / directions I should explore to do something simple but future proof.

Thanks for looking!

Regards,

Comment: Sounds very interesting. Could you provide some typical use cases for adding new data to the system and for retrieving data. Do you need to monitor changes in files? From what I have read, you can use [mapper-attachments](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/master/mapper-attachments.html) plugin to index files.

Comment: Let's supposed I want to archive all email communications ( EML files ). These will never change of course alongside with tons of CSV and other tabular data and I want to form a relationship between them. I could use Kibana to search among the emails and on the same time I also need to be able to store simply reports e.g. CSV files which will need to analytical work etc. But to start with email archiving is the first step than tagging emails and also tag tabular data and reports and perhaps define relationships among them

Comment: The key problem is how I could get the EML ( emails ) and tabular data. Supposing they do not change any more once they saved on the filesystem into Elasticsearch? I guess this is the first step.